# How to move files to another directory which are created today in Shell?

Tags: shell

I have following script

```
find . -mtime 0 -type f -exec ls -ltr {} \; | grep "$(date +%d|sed 's,^0,,g') ..:.." | while read fname; do
   echo "$fname"
done
```

And I am able to print file detail. How can I move test1.txt test2.txt files to another directory?

Output:

```
[nca@ldc039 failure]$ . ../../scripts/retryFailedFiles.sh 
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 nca nca 0 Feb 29 16:16 ./test1.txt
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 nca nca 0 Feb 29 16:16 ./test2.txt
```

Comment: unclear what you mean by "fire `mv` command on it". Do you want to move test1.txt to test2.txt? Please edit your Q, rather than replying in comments. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

```
# You can use the option -1tr instead -ltr :
find . -mtime 0 -type f -exec ls -1tr {} \; | while read fname; do
echo "$fname" 
mv $fname newfolder
done

# Or, by using the following commande :
find . -mtime 0 -type f -exec mv {} newfolder \;
```